# Magento2 Estimate Shipping rate and Tax in minicart

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I have spent lot of time in to include "Estimate ans shipping rate" in mini cart at header so user can also check shipping rate from minicart rather than to move on to cart page.
I could'nt get solution to include "Estimate and shipping rate" in minicart.

Any help or solution will be appreciated.